# Efficiently populating a 2D SciPy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, performance, scipy

I want to populate a huge sparse matrix in python, with the aim to implement Crank-Nicolson numerical method in 2D.

I did it by lopping through all the interior nodes using two nested for loops, but it is extremely slow.
Because it is a nested for loop with matrices, I thought of Numba, but it doesn't work with sparse matrices.
I cannot convert the matrix to a dense format before passing it as an argument to a numba-jitted function, because of memory issues.

I want to ask what shall I look for in order to make the function populating the `A` matrix below quicker?

I tried with `scipy.sparse.diags`, but I again ended up using two nested for loops, just as in the (naive) code below.

The problem is that the `k` value is computed from `i` and `j`, and I don't know how to manipulate it without the double for loop.

The code which populates the `A` matrix with the double for loop is:

```py
# @njit
def populate_A_matrix_b_vector(psi_gr, timeste, A, b, sys_float_info_min):

    # Fill all the interior nodes
    # -------------------------------------

    # Utilities:
    two_lambd = 2 * gl.lambd
    oneover4_times_1over_deltazsq = 0.25 / (gl.delta_z**2)
    oneover2_times_1over_deltazsq = 0.5 / (gl.delta_z**2)

    # For the interior nodes:
    for i in range(1, gl.N_z_divs):
        for j in range(1, gl.N_epsilon_divs):

            k = j*(gl.N_z_divs+1) + i
            
            ratio = 1 / ( (2*gl.lambd**2) * (j*gl.delta_epsilon)**two_lambd )

            A[k, k] = (-1/gl.delta_time) - ratio * (j**2 - (gl.lambd-0.5)**2 * 0.5) - oneover2_times_1over_deltazsq - \
                           0.5 * Voft_OFF_imag(i, j, gl.m)
                           
            A[k, k+1] = oneover4_times_1over_deltazsq
            A[k, k-1] = oneover4_times_1over_deltazsq
            A[k, k + (gl.N_z_divs+1)] = ratio * ( j**2*0.5 - (gl.lambd-1)*j*0.5 )
            A[k, k - (gl.N_z_divs+1)] = ratio * ( j**2*0.5 + (gl.lambd-1)*j*0.5 )

            b[k] = psi_gr[i,  j, timeste] * ( (-1/gl.delta_time) + ratio*j**2 - (gl.lambd-0.5)**2*0.5 + oneover2_times_1over_deltazsq + \
                                0.5 * Voft_OFF_imag(i, j, gl.m)  ) + \
                   psi_gr[i+1, j, timeste] * (-oneover4_times_1over_deltazsq) + \
                   psi_gr[i-1, j, timeste] * (-oneover4_times_1over_deltazsq) + \
                   psi_gr[i,   j+1, timeste] * ( -ratio * (j**2 * 0.5 - (gl.lambd-1) * j * 0.5)   ) + \
                   psi_gr[i,   j-1, timeste] * ( -ratio * (j**2 * 0.5 + (gl.lambd-1) * j * 0.5)   )
            
        if (i % 50 == 0):
            print("we have done iter" + str(i*gl.N_epsilon_divs + j) + "out of" + str(gl.N_z_divs*gl.N_epsilon_divs) + "iters")

    # Fill boundaries
    # -------------------------

    # Bottom boundary except corners: j = 0; i = 1, 2, 3, ..., gl.N_z_divs - 1
    j = 0
    for i in range(1, gl.N_z_divs):
        k = j*(gl.N_z_divs+1) + i
        A[k, k] = 1

        if ( np.real(psi_gr[i, 2, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min and np.imag(psi_gr[i, 2, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min):
            alpha = psi_gr[i, 1, timeste] / psi_gr[i, 2, timeste]
            if (np.arctan(np.imag(alpha) / np.real(alpha))) < 0:
                alpha = np.abs(alpha)
        else:
            alpha = 0.0

        # A[k, k+(gl.N_z_divs+1)] = alpha
        A[k, k+(gl.N_z_divs+1)] = 0.0
    
    # Top boundary except corners: j = gl.N_epsilon_divs; i = 1, 2, 3, ..., gl.N_z_divs - 1
    j = gl.N_epsilon_divs
    for i in range(1, gl.N_z_divs):
        k = j*(gl.N_z_divs+1) + i
        A[k, k] = 1

        if (np.real(psi_gr[i, gl.N_epsilon_divs-2, timeste])>= sys_float_info_min and np.imag(psi_gr[i, gl.N_epsilon_divs-2, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min):
            alpha = psi_gr[i, gl.N_epsilon_divs-1, timeste] / psi_gr[i, gl.N_epsilon_divs-2, timeste]
            if (np.arctan(np.imag(alpha) / np.real(alpha))) < 0:
                alpha = np.abs(alpha)
        else:
            alpha = 0.0

        # A[k, k-(gl.N_z_divs+1)] = alpha
        A[k, k-(gl.N_z_divs+1)] = 0.0

    # Left boundary except corners: i = 0; j = 1, 2, 3, ..., gl.N_epsilon_divs - 1
    i = 0
    for j in range(1, gl.N_epsilon_divs):
        k = j*(gl.N_z_divs+1) + i
        A[k, k] = 1

        if (np.real(psi_gr[2, j, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min and np.imag(psi_gr[2, j, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min):
            alpha = psi_gr[1, j, timeste] / psi_gr[2, j, timeste]
            if (np.arctan(np.imag(alpha) / np.real(alpha))) < 0:
                alpha = np.abs(alpha)
        else:
            alpha = 0.0

       # A[k, k+1] = alpha
        A[k, k+1] = 0.0
    
    # Right boundary except corners: i = N_z_divs; j = 1, 2, 3, ..., gl.N_epsilon_divs - 1
    i = gl.N_z_divs
    for j in range(1, gl.N_epsilon_divs):
        k = j*(gl.N_z_divs+1) + i
        A[k, k] = 1

        if (np.real(psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs-2, j, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min and np.imag(psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs-2, j, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min):
            alpha = psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs-1, j, timeste] / psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs-2, j, timeste]
            if (np.arctan(np.imag(alpha) / np.real(alpha))) < 0:
                alpha = np.abs(alpha)
        else:
            alpha = 0.0
        
        A[k, k-1] = alpha
        # A[k, k-1] = 0.0


    # Bottom left corner: i = j = 0
    i = 0;  j = 0
    k = j*(gl.N_z_divs+1) + i
    A[k, k] = 1

    if (np.real(psi_gr[2, 0, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min and np.imag(psi_gr[2, 0, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min):
        alpha1 = psi_gr[1, 0, timeste] / psi_gr[2, 0, timeste]
        if (np.arctan(np.imag(alpha1) / np.real(alpha1))) < 0:
            alpha1 = np.abs(alpha1)
    else:
        alpha1 = 0.0
    
    if (np.real(psi_gr[0, 2, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min and np.imag(psi_gr[0, 2, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min):
        alpha2 = psi_gr[0, 1, timeste] / psi_gr[0, 2, timeste]
        if (np.arctan(np.imag(alpha2) / np.real(alpha2))) < 0:
            alpha2 = np.abs(alpha2)
    else:
        alpha2 = 0.0

    # A[k, k+1]                 = - 0.5 * alpha1
    # A[k, k + (gl.N_z_divs+1)] = - 0.5 * alpha2
    A[k, k+1] = 0.0
    A[k, k + (gl.N_z_divs+1)] = 0.0


    # Bottom right corner: i = N_z_divs; j = 0
    i = gl.N_z_divs;  j = 0
    k = j*(gl.N_z_divs+1) + i
    A[k, k] = 1

    if (np.real(psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs-2, 0, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min and np.imag(psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs-2, 0, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min):
        alpha1 = psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs-1, 0, timeste] / psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs-2, 0, timeste]
        if (np.arctan(np.imag(alpha1) / np.real(alpha1))) < 0:
            alpha1 = np.abs(alpha1)
    else:
        alpha1 = 0.0
    
    if (np.real(psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs, 2, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min and np.imag(psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs, 2, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min):
        alpha2 = psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs, 1, timeste] / psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs, 2, timeste]
        if (np.arctan(np.imag(alpha2) / np.real(alpha2))) < 0:
            alpha2 = np.abs(alpha2)
    else:
        alpha2 = 0.0

    # A[k, k-1] = - 0.5 * alpha1
    # A[k, k + (gl.N_z_divs+1)] = - 0.5 * alpha2
    A[k, k-1] = 0.0
    A[k, k + (gl.N_z_divs+1)] = 0.0


    # Top left corner: i = 0; j = N_epsilon_divs
    i = 0;  j = gl.N_epsilon_divs
    k = j*(gl.N_z_divs+1) + i
    A[k, k] = 1

    if (np.real(psi_gr[2, gl.N_epsilon_divs, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min and np.imag(psi_gr[2, gl.N_epsilon_divs, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min):
        alpha1 = psi_gr[1, gl.N_epsilon_divs, timeste] / psi_gr[2, gl.N_epsilon_divs, timeste]
        if (np.arctan(np.imag(alpha1) / np.real(alpha1))) < 0:
            alpha1  = np.abs(alpha1)
    else:
        alpha1 = 0.0
    
    if (np.real(psi_gr[0, gl.N_epsilon_divs-2, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min and np.imag(psi_gr[0, gl.N_epsilon_divs-2, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min):
        alpha2 = psi_gr[0, gl.N_epsilon_divs-1, timeste] / psi_gr[0, gl.N_epsilon_divs-2, timeste]
        if (np.arctan(np.imag(alpha2) / np.real(alpha2))) < 0:
            alpha2 = np.abs(alpha2)
    else:
        alpha2 = 0.0

    # A[k, k+1] = - 0.5 * alpha1
    # A[k, k - (gl.N_z_divs+1)] = - 0.5 * alpha2
    A[k, k+1] = 0.0
    A[k, k - (gl.N_z_divs+1)] = 0.0

    # Top right corner: i = N_z_divs; j = N_epsilon_divs
    i = gl.N_z_divs;  j = gl.N_epsilon_divs 
    k = j*(gl.N_z_divs+1) + i
    A[k, k] = 1

    if (np.real(psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs-2, gl.N_epsilon_divs, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min and np.imag(psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs-2, gl.N_epsilon_divs, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min):
        alpha1 = psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs-1, gl.N_epsilon_divs, timeste] / psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs-2, gl.N_epsilon_divs, timeste]
        if (np.arctan(np.imag(alpha1) / np.real(alpha1))) < 0:
            alpha1 = np.abs(alpha1)
    else:
        alpha1 = 0.0
    
    if (np.real(psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs, gl.N_epsilon_divs-2, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min and np.imag(psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs, gl.N_epsilon_divs-2, timeste]) >= sys_float_info_min):
        alpha2 = psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs, gl.N_epsilon_divs-1, timeste] / psi_gr[gl.N_z_divs, gl.N_epsilon_divs-2, timeste]
        if (np.arctan(np.imag(alpha2) / np.real(alpha2))) < 0:
            alpha2 = np.abs(alpha2)
    else:
        alpha2 = 0.0

    # A[k, k-1] = - 0.5 * alpha1
    # A[k, k -(gl.N_z_divs+1)] = - 0.5 * alpha2
    A[k, k-1] = 0.0
    A[k, k -(gl.N_z_divs+1)] = 0.0

    return A, b

@njit
def Voft_OFF_imag(i, j, m):
    # this is the same as Voft_OFF() above, because there is no modification due to the imag. time propagation (delta_time --> -1j*delta_time) appearing in Voft_OFF (as there is no E-field turned on)
    ii = i - gl.K/2
    term1  = -1 / sqrt(  (j*gl.delta_epsilon)**(2*gl.lambd) + (ii*gl.delta_z)**2  ) #  - 1 / sqrt(...)
    term2 = m**2 / ( 2*(j*gl.delta_epsilon)**(2*gl.lambd) )
    return (term1 + term2)
```

and I use it as:

```
def solve_for_1timestep_imag(psi_gr, timeste):

    size = (gl.N_z_divs+1) * (gl.N_epsilon_divs+1)

    A = sparse.dok_matrix( (size, size), dtype=np.complex64)
    # b = sparse.dok_array((size, 1), dtype=np.complex64)
    b = np.zeros( (size, 1), dtype=np.complex64)

    sys_float_info_min = sys.float_info.min
    A, b = populate_A_matrix_b_vector(psi_gr, timeste, A, b, sys_float_info_min)
    ...
    ...
```

The `gl.py` file is:

```
import numpy as np

Energy_1s_au = np.float64(-0.5) # -13.6 eV in atomic units of energy
m = np.float64(0.0) # magnetic Q number

omega = np.float64(0.2) 
E0 = np.float64(0.3)

N_timesteps_imag = np.int32(120)

lambd = np.float64(1.5)

delta_time = np.float64(0.01)

N_epsilon_divs = np.int32(200)
N_z_divs = np.int32(500)
K = N_z_divs # equal to the variable N_z_divs

delta_epsilon = np.float64(0.1)
delta_z = np.float64(0.1)

z_max = (N_z_divs/2) * delta_z
epsilon_range = np.linspace(0.0, N_epsilon_divs*delta_epsilon, N_epsilon_divs+1)
z_range = np.linspace(-z_max, z_max, N_z_divs+1)
```

That function populating the `A` matrix is the bottleneck of my code and I would greatly appreciate any help on how to make it at least a little bit faster.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scipy sparse matrices are pretty slow. This is especially true for the DOK matrices using inefficient hash-tables internally. However, **reading/Setting a specific cell of a sparse matrices in a loop is insanely slow** (eg. each access takes 10~15 us on my machine). You should avoid that like the plague.

One solution to solve this problem is to create an array of indices and values and write the values to the space matrix in **vectorized** way. The computation of the indices/values can be optimized with Numba. Here is an example:

```py
@nb.njit
def gen_indexed_values(psi_gr, timeste, b):
    two_lambd = 2 * gl.lambd
    oneover4_times_1over_deltazsq = 0.25 / (gl.delta_z**2)
    oneover2_times_1over_deltazsq = 0.5 / (gl.delta_z**2)

    res_size = (gl.N_z_divs-1) * (gl.N_epsilon_divs-1)
    A_idx = np.empty(res_size, dtype=np.int32)
    A_values = np.empty((3, res_size), dtype=np.complex64)
    cur = 0

    for i in range(1, gl.N_z_divs):
        for j in range(1, gl.N_epsilon_divs):
            k = j*(gl.N_z_divs+1) + i
            ratio = 1 / ( (2*gl.lambd**2) * (j*gl.delta_epsilon)**two_lambd )

            A_idx[cur] = k
            A_values[0, cur] = (-1/gl.delta_time) - ratio * (j**2 - (gl.lambd-0.5)**2 * 0.5) - oneover2_times_1over_deltazsq - \
                                0.5 * Voft_OFF_imag(i, j, gl.m)
            A_values[1, cur] = ratio * ( j**2*0.5 - (gl.lambd-1)*j*0.5 )
            A_values[2, cur] = ratio * ( j**2*0.5 + (gl.lambd-1)*j*0.5 )

            b[k] = psi_gr[i,  j, timeste] * ( (-1/gl.delta_time) + ratio*j**2 - (gl.lambd-0.5)**2*0.5 + oneover2_times_1over_deltazsq + \
                                0.5 * Voft_OFF_imag(i, j, gl.m)  ) + \
                   psi_gr[i+1, j, timeste] * (-oneover4_times_1over_deltazsq) + \
                   psi_gr[i-1, j, timeste] * (-oneover4_times_1over_deltazsq) + \
                   psi_gr[i,   j+1, timeste] * ( -ratio * (j**2 * 0.5 - (gl.lambd-1) * j * 0.5)   ) + \
                   psi_gr[i,   j-1, timeste] * ( -ratio * (j**2 * 0.5 + (gl.lambd-1) * j * 0.5)   )

            cur += 1

    return A_idx, A_values

def populate_A_matrix_b_vector(psi_gr, timeste, A, b, sys_float_info_min):
    # Utilities:
    two_lambd = 2 * gl.lambd
    oneover4_times_1over_deltazsq = 0.25 / (gl.delta_z**2)
    oneover2_times_1over_deltazsq = 0.5 / (gl.delta_z**2)

    # For the interior nodes:
    A_idx, A_values = gen_indexed_values(psi_gr, timeste, b)
    A[A_idx, A_idx] = A_values[0,:]
    A[A_idx, A_idx+1] = oneover4_times_1over_deltazsq
    A[A_idx, A_idx-1] = oneover4_times_1over_deltazsq
    A[A_idx, A_idx + (gl.N_z_divs+1)] = A_values[1,:]
    A[A_idx, A_idx - (gl.N_z_divs+1)] = A_values[2,:]

    # [...]
```

This is about **22 times faster** on my machine. Using another kind of sparse matrix may help to improve performance.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate it! Still, I get a strange warning, which didn't appear when I was doing my naive attempt I designed: ``RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in square
  tp = np.trapz(np.abs(psi_gr[:, :, timestep+1])**2, gl.z_range, axis=0) # tp (temporary storage) is shape (N_epsilon_divs, )   RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in add
  ret = (d * (y[tuple(slice1)] + y[tuple(slice2)]) / 2.0).sum(axis)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  psi_gr[:, :, timestep+1] /= sqrt(res)``

Comment: So basically it doesn't work now, it's probably something related to indexing when you vectorized, as I checked the formulas you introduced and there are no mistakes in there. Can you spot the problem? I will search further

Comment: I believe I found the mistake: in your code, in ``populate_A_matrix_b_vector`` function, the RHS A_values[1,0] shall be A_values[1, :] and A_values[2, 0] shall be A_values[2, :]. Correct?

Comment: You are right. This was a mistake. Thank you. I also fixed the types of the `np.empty` calls. That being said, I found that the `complex64` is suspicious in the initial code since `complex64` is for complex numbers with a real/imaginary part in `float32`. Is this intended or you wanted to use `float64` values? If so, you need `np.complex128`.

Comment: Thank you, I also wrote myself the np.empty calls with dtype inside them. Yes, I changed ``complex64`` to ``complex128``. Now all runs fine and is way faster (although not instant ...). Thank you a lot!